# Prove $\cos x \cosh x +1=0$ has infinitely many real roots.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove $\cos x \cosh x +1=0$ has infinitely many real roots.
Tried writing 
$$\cos x=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
But can not go further.

This problem has part (b), prove for large $x$ the root approximate those of $\cos x=0$. Since don't know how to prove part (a), so did not look at part (b) yet...

Comment: Do you want/have to use complex functions?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem on appropriately chosen intervals?

Comment: Draw the function and use the insight to construct an argument that there are infinitely many roots

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I tried to find some intervals that $f$ have different sign at the end points. However, that doesn't prove there are infinite many solutions.

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem. You won't be able to solve for the roots, but it's easy to find infinitely many places when it's larger and smaller than $1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, I tried to find some intervals that ff have different sign at the end points. However, that doesn't prove there are infinite many solutions.

Comment: @Nan when $\cos(x)$ is positive, clearly the product is larger than $-1$. This happens at least at every even integer multiple of $\pi$. Then $\cosh$ increases without bound. You can ensure that there is some $N$ where afterwards it's always larger than $2$. Then the product is smaller than $-1$ at odd multiples of $\pi$ forever after. BAM. Infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for odd multiples of $\pi$, $f(x)=\cosh x \cos x + 1$ is negative (since $\cos x =-1$ and $\cosh x >1$ for $|x|>1$), and at even multiples of $\pi$ it is positive since $\cos x=1$ and using similar reason as before.

Clearly, $f(x)$ is continuous, and it switches sign on the interval $[\pi k,\pi k + \pi]$ for integer $k$, so it contains a zero in each of those intervals (which there are infinitely many).

Comment: How about part (b), I mean when $\cos x \approx 0$, should $f \approx 1$ but why $f \approx 0$?

Comment: If $f(x) = 0$ then $x$ satisfies $\cos x = - \frac{1}{\cosh x}$. For large $x$, $\cosh x$ is large, so $x$ must be such that $\cos x$ is small.